# Не получается изменить url через hash. Помогите найти ошибку в JS

Tags: javascript, html5

На сайте есть модалки. Вызываются через uikit 2.25  - UIkit.modal(). 
Мне нужно чтобы при вызове добавлялся id окна в url. 
Консоль чистая. Никаких ошибок не вываливается.
НЕ могу понять где ошибка. Почему не работает?

```js
 let isChangingModal = false;
       
        window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
           
            for (let modal of document.querySelectorAll("[data-popup]")) {
                modal.addEventListener("beforeshow", ()=>{
                    isChangingModal = true;
                    window.location.hash = "#" + modal.getAttribute("data-popup");
                });
                modal.addEventListener("beforehide", ()=>{
                    isChangingModal = true;
                    window.location.hash = "#";
                });
            }
           
            showModalFromURL();
        });    
       
        function showModalFromURL() {
            if (isChangingModal) {
                isChangingModal = false;
                return;
            }
            let modal = document.querySelector(`[data-popup="${window.location.hash.slice(1)}"]`);
            if (modal) {
                UIkit.modal(modal).show();
            }
        }
       
        window.onhashchange = showModalFromURL;
```

```html
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
       
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.3/css/uikit.min.css" />-->
       
        <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.3/js/uikit.min.js"></script> -->
     
      <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-->
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.25.0/css/uikit.min.css" />
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.25.0/js/uikit.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><button class="uk-button uk-button-large uk-button-danger" data-uk-modal="{target:'#my-id2081'}">Подробнее</button></p>
<div id="my-id2081" class="uk-modal" data-popup="test">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
        <a class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></a>

     
<br>Милые дамы! </br> 
<br>Не пропустите!<b> Набор в мини-группу "Богемская растяжка"!</b></br>  

<br>Богемский интенсив для тех, кто не боится окунуться в мир приятной (и не очень) боли, криков, стонов, устранения закрепощенности и зажимов в мышцах, да-да, всё это о растяжке! А вы о чем подумали? :)</br> 


  <a class="uk-button uk-button-primary" href="kupit-kartu ">Узнать стоимость карты</a>
        </div>
</div>
    </body>
```

На отдельной странице можно посмотреть тут http://test.endlesstest.ru

Comment: Так вы посмотрите, событие `beforeshow` вызывается?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, я не очень силён в js. Но кажется как раз в этих событиях проблема.. А это браузерные события?

Comment: Нет, это не стандартные события. Поэтому хорошо бы приложить информацию к вопросу, что за `UIkit` такой.

Comment: Uikit наподобие бутстрапа фреймворк. https://getuikit.com/docs/modal#javascript
Да, я понял. Эти события из новой версии этого фрэймворка.
Но у меня на сайте старая. 
Возможно как-то без этих событий реализовать данную задачу?

Comment: если используется вторая версия, нужно смотреть справку именно по ней, я в прошлом вопросе ссылку давал, там другие события. По умолчанию для третьей версии все идет

Comment: @Grundy, я смотрел. Там только 2 ивента которые отвечают за показ и скрытие окна, а аналогичных как в 3 версии там нет.

Comment: ну так надо и использовать эти два эвента. Их как раз хватает: при показе и при скрытии

Comment: я пробовал поменять на эти события, но нет результата. Как я понимаю они немного другие. В 3 версии событие -"до появления окна", а во 2 "когда окно открыто". Возможно в этом дело.

Comment: @Григорий, в чем принципиальная разница?